# fullcalender doesnt display Previous/Next navigation buttons, and a buttons to switch the Calendar view between month and agendaWeek

Tags: fullcalendar

I added a calendar to my site using fullcalendar the calendar display but i cant see the Previous/Next navigation buttons, and a buttons to switch the Calendar view between month and agendaWeek

my code:

```
  <script>

    $(document).ready(function () {



        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '2014-09-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [

                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2014-09-12T10:30:00',
                    end: '2014-09-12T12:30:00'
                }
            ]
        });

    });

</script>
<style>

body {
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
}

#calendar {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case I remove this

```html
<link type="text/css" href="fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

from header section and I can see the navigation buttons.

Comment: This was my issue.  In my ASP .NET MVC project I was bundling the fullcalendar.css and fullcalendar.print.css sheets together.

Comment: as a fix I had to add a script reference to the print.css with 'media="print"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the latest version of Fullcalendar which is 2.1.1. You can download that [here](http://fullcalendar.io/download/). You should include the following files in your `<head>` section:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.css' />
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.7.0/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
```

Refer to this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/k60kkos0/) to see it working.

Comment: I have the new version, I tried to run it from jsfiddle and it is OK but it is not working from the new project i opened there are references for all the files, and it is display the calender table but not the other buttons, furthermore in jsfiddle the events are created with a blue background , and in my site the events are without background

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle that demonstrates your issue?